# SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm getting that exception when I do an insert in my SQLite database

The following code gives me the exception:

```
mDbHelper.createUser("pablo","a","a","a","a");
```

The code from mDbHelper (MyDbAdapter):

```
private static final String USER_TABLE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE user ( email varchar, password varchar, fullName varchar, mobilePhone varchar, mobileOperatingSystem varchar, PRIMARY KEY  (email))";

public long createUser(String email, String password, String fullName, String mobilePhone, String mobileOperatingSystem) 
    {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put("email",email);
        initialValues.put("password",password);
        initialValues.put("fullName",fullName);
        initialValues.put("mobilePhone",mobilePhone);
        initialValues.put("mobileOperatingSystem",mobileOperatingSystem);
        return mDb.insert("user", null, initialValues);
    }
```

The exception is created on the last line: `return mDb.insert("user", null, initialValues);`

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You are inserting a duplicate `email`.

Plus the recommended way is to have a `_ID` column as primary key, even if you don't use it. This way on future uses, like use in a Adapter or List, you won't have to workaround.

Comment: no i'm not, the database is empty, and pablo is the first email i am inserting on it....

Comment: Double check again, you missed something there. It should not be empty.

Comment: ohhhh yes you are on true, the values i inserted are saved permanently, each time i am testing my app i am trying to add a value that is currently saved on the database... i did'nt know that..... and how can i clean the database each tiem i open my app ?

Comment: I don't know how you structured, but probably you have to increase the version number and recreate the tables.

Comment: To clarify, op isn't _inserting_ a duplicate `email` field in the `insert(...)` statement, but is specifying the `email` column twice (therefore a duplicate column) in the `CREATE TABLE` statement.